# Get ERC20 token buy/sell tax

Tags: erc-20, ethers.js, javascript, eth-call

I am trying to implement a method for calculating token buy/sell tax. The one that devs implement it in the `transfer()` function.

I've done some research and there are 2 options.

1. `eth_call` - simulate a swap, calculate the difference
2. deploy the `ERC20` smart contract on a local hardhat/ganache, execute swap and see the difference

The `eth_call` seems to be better for me but I'm facing some issues.

```
 // Encode function data
        const encodedData = router.interface.encodeFunctionData('swapExactETHForTokens', [
            0,
            path,
            to,
            deadline,
        ]);

        // Get amountsOut using eth_call, performs a SIMULATION
        const callResult = await this.provider.call({
            data: encodedData,
            value: parseUnits('2', 18),
            to: constants.UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
        });

        console.log('callResult', callResult);

        // Decode result
        const decodedResult = router.interface.decodeFunctionResult(
            'swapExactETHForTokens',
            callResult
        );
```

it does not return the actual amount including taxes, the response is just an array of the amounts out first is amount of ETH and second is the token amount. if I set the amountIn 0, then I get 0% tax, if I increase it then the amountOut of token decreases.